# Can Rust enforce external conditions on Struct fields?

Tags: rust, struct, constructor

Suppose I have the following struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: Vec<f64>,
}
```

Here the fields, `a` and `b` are `Vec` but the question is generally applicable to any types with some interdependent condition.

I want to enforce construction ***with the condition that `Vec`s are of the same length***:

```rust
impl A {
    fn new(a: &[i32], b: &[f64]) -> Self {
        if a.len() != b.len() {
            panic!("Bad sizes.")
        }
        Self {
            a: Vec::from(a),
            b: Vec::from(b),
        }
    }
}
```

This does not prevent the direct construction of `A` if the fields are directly populated, e.g.

```rust
    let y = A {
        a: Vec::from(&[1, 2]),
        b: Vec::from(&[1.])
    };
```

***What is the idiomatic way of enforcing the condition?***

I wonder if private/public statements can enforce this for crate users, but still remain a potential issue for the crate developers.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b743ab54a0616d7530cdd20bb52d5135

Comment: Since you didn't declare the struct or it's fields `pub` only the module that struct is declared in can use the literal syntax. Or in other words, your code is the idiomatic way to enforce that condition.